# ipad/iphone video not switching to fullscreen mode

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, event-handling, html5-video

I am working to make a video play with fullscreen mode. all browsers are working including safari. but the ipad/iphone not at all responding. here is my condition and function, can any one help me to sort out the issue?

code:

```
if(fullscreen && !currentVideo.paused){
            if (currentVideo.requestFullScreen) {
                currentVideo.requestFullScreen();
              } else if (currentVideo.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                currentVideo.mozRequestFullScreen();
              } else if (currentVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen || currentVideo.webkitEnterFullscreen) {
                currentVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen() || currentVideo.webkitEnterFullscreen();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether that is even possible? Not even YouTube is able to give me fullscreen video on the iPad (in Safari, I'm not talking about the app).  That makes me think there might be no way

Comment: are you trying to play the video in webview?

Comment: yes. i am making this video for responsive website. (jquerymobile i use)

Comment: @Pekka I can watch youtube videos fullscreen (mobile safari). I think that has always been an option.

Comment: @Joonas now that you mention it, I remember: used to be able to do that too. But I don't seem to have the option on iOS 6 when on youtube.com. I'll check it out later.

Comment: @Pekka I have ios 6 too.  -- http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me...

```
setTimeout(function () {
        if(fullscreen && !currentVideo.paused){
            if (currentVideo.requestFullScreen) {
                currentVideo.requestFullScreen();
              } else if (currentVideo.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                currentVideo.mozRequestFullScreen();
              } else if (currentVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                currentVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen();
             } else if (currentVideo.webkitEnterFullscreen){
                currentVideo.webkitEnterFullscreen();
             }
        }
    },1000);        
} );
```

Thanks to all.